# Configuring scroller height while using .grid()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a program using tkinter.
I want scrollbar height to be same as listbox height. In my previous programs when i used .pack() method, i just used this:

```
lbox = Listbox()
lbox.pack(side=LEFT)
scroll = Scrollbar(command=lbox.yview)
scroll.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
lbox.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
```

Here's what i get:

[image: screenshot]

But now i'm using .grid() instead of .pack(), and i don't know how to make scrollbar have a same height as listbox.
I've tried this:

```
self.clientsList = Listbox(self.root, width=50, height=10)
self.clientsList.grid(row=0, column=0)

self.scroller = Scrollbar(command=self.clientsList.yview)
self.scroller.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NE)

self.clientsList.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroller.set)
```

And it won't work. I'm getting this:

[image: screenshot 2]

How could i fix this?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Use `sticky=NS`.

Comment: @Atlas435 yes, I could. But i didn't found exactly what i want. I found some results, but they were over complicated. And now, when someone googles "tkinter  scroller height grid", they can find this, and see the perfect answer.

Comment: Or maybe it is just another thread that makes it harder to find a well explained answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `sticky=NE` to `sticky=NS` in grid of scrollbar.

**My test code:**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

clientsList = tk.Listbox(root, width=50, height=10)
clientsList.grid(row=0, column=0)

scroller = tk.Scrollbar()
scroller.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)

tk.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

[image: output]